# How to access the sockJS event-bus via ws-protocol?

Tags: groovy, websocket, vert.x, sockjs, event-bus

I have a verticle:

```
class GatewayVerticle extends GroovyVerticle {

  @Override
  void start() throws Exception {

    EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus()
    eb.consumer( 'inbound' ){ Message<String> msg ->
      eb.send 'log', "${msg.address()}: ${msg.body()}"
      eb.send msg.address(), "echo: ${msg.body()}"
    }

    def opts = [ ... ] as Map<String,Object>

    SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create( vertx ).bridge( opts ){ BridgeEvent event ->
      println "event: ${event.type()} -> ${event.rawMessage}"
      event.complete true
    }

    Router router = Router.router vertx
    router.route( '/eventbus/*' ).handler sockJSHandler

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler( router.&accept ).listen 8811
  }
}
```

I can communicate with the event-bus in a HTML-JS-client so:

```
  eb = new EventBus( 'http://localhost:8811/eventbus' );
  eb.registerHandler(address, function(error, msg) {
    console.info( "Address:" + address + " Message:" + msg.body + "<br>");
  });
```

Now, I want to use a propper `ws://localhost:8811/eventbus`, but it fails...

The trick with direct Websocket works only if I introduce another handler:

```
vertx.createHttpServer().websocketHandler( wsHandler ).listen 8822
```

and the JS is working just fine:

```
var ws8822 = new WebSocket( 'ws://localhost:8822' );
ws8822.send( JSON.stringify( { text:'KKKKKKK' } ) );
```

but in this case I'm missing the whole event-bus stuff.

Is it possible to access the bridged over sockJSHandler event-bus using the native ws-protocol?